# How to identify all the connected vertices from a list of coordinate pairs?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

Consider a list (`edge`) as

```
edge = {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 1}, {1, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 
   1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 1}, {4, 1}}, {{1, 
   1}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 
   1}}, {{1, 2}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 2}, {4, 1}}, {{1, 
   2}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {1, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 
   4}}, {{1, 3}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 1}}, {{1, 3}, {4, 4}}, {{1, 
   4}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 4}, {2, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{1, 4}, {4, 
   1}}, {{1, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 4}}, {{2, 1}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 
   1}, {4, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {4, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {3, 4}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 
   1}}, {{2, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 1}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 4}}, {{4, 
   1}, {4, 4}}};
```

Each pair (e.g. `{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}`) indicates the existence of an edge between the corresponding points. Now I wish to find the set of connected points from `edge`.

For example, from the given set, I can manually find

```
set1= {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 
   1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {4, 4}}
```

Basically, if there exists a path between `{1,1}` and `{x,y}`, `{x,y}` should be included in `set1`. I wish to find all such sets which are mutually exclusive (disjoint) and all the vertices within any set are connected.

How can I do this for a large set of points (`edge` is just a small subset)?

Comment: `ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ edge]`?

Comment: For this dataset, it does give exactly the result you said you needed. If it is not connected components that you need, can you update the question and clarify?

Comment: @Szabolcs Sorry for my earlier comment. It works and works perfectly. I have deleted that comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ edge]
```

> {{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {4, 4}}}

In general, you can use a list or a pattern of vertices as the second argument of `ConnectedComponents` to get the components that contain at least one vertex from the specified list of vertices. In OP's example, since there is a single connected component and it contains the vertex `{1,1}`, we get the same result with `ConnectedComponents[UndirectedEdge @@@ edge, {{1,1}}]`.